# Java buttons not working in Firefox when Page is Made W3 Compliant

Tags: javascript, firefox, w3c

I have some Menu Buttons that when I declare a DocType page (Trans or Strict) the Button cease to work in Firefox, but work in IE. If I declare the page as `<HTML>` the buttons work.

The HTML Code that uses the JS file is below, not sure you need to see the JS Code as this works, it's the HTML that is the problem (I think)

```
<a href="http://dukescottages.com/" onmouseover="setOverImg('1','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu1','button1');" onmouseout="setOutImg('1','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu1\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button1up.png" border="0" id="button1" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a><a href="Link 2" onmouseover="setOverImg('2','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu2','button2');" onmouseout="setOutImg('2','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu2\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button2up.png" border="0" id="button2" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a><a href="http://dukescottages.com/prettyphoto.htm" onmouseover="setOverImg('3','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu3','button3');" onmouseout="setOutImg('3','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu3\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button3up.png" border="0" id="button3" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a><a href="http://dukescottages.com/Guestbook/ddgb.php" onmouseover="setOverImg('4','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu4','button4');" onmouseout="setOutImg('4','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu4\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button4up.png" border="0" id="button4" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a><a href="http://dukescottages.com/contactform.htm" onmouseover="setOverImg('5','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu5','button5');" onmouseout="setOutImg('5','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu5\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button5up.png" border="0" id="button5" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a><a href="*" onmouseover="setOverImg('6','');overSub=true;showSubMenu('submenu6','button6');" onmouseout="setOutImg('6','');overSub=false;setTimeout('hideSubMenu(\'submenu6\')',delay);" target=""><img src="buttons/button6up.png" border="0" id="button6" vspace="0" hspace="0"></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Golly but that code sure is hard to read, with it all being on one line and everything.

Comment: Also, you surely mean "JavaScript" buttons, or just "buttons", since there doesn't appear to be anything here pertaining to Java.

Comment: What does the `setOverImg` function look like?  Chances are it's doing things that work in quirks mode but not standards mode in Gecko but work in both modes in IE (like relying on the global scope polluter would be my first guess).

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess, but perhaps Firefox wants you to close those `<img>` tags in strict mode.

Either close them with `<img src="buttons/button1up.png" border="0" id="button1" vspace="0" hspace="0"></img>` or, if XHTML, `<img src="buttons/button1up.png" border="0" id="button1" vspace="0" hspace="0" />`

Comment: This is setOverImg Function function setOverImg(But, ID) {
 document.getElementById('button' + But + ID).src = buttonFolder + overSources[But-1];
}